# Filter column matches from two files

Tags: awk

I have two files with the format:

```
number|string
```

I want to create a third file with the contents of file 1 and without the matches between both files on the second column.

file1

```
1|abc
2|bcd
3|cde
```

file2

```
1|bcd
2|def
```

file3

```
1|abc
3|cde
```

Is this correct?

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$2 not in a{print $0}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code/efforts. Please do add input and expected output too in your question go make it more clear.

Comment: Please do mention logic of comparing these 2 files in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F '|' 'FNR == NR {skip[$2]; next} !($2 in skip)' file2 file1 > file3

cat file3

1|abc
3|cde
```